# SQL Server Parameter Table Values inside SQL query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, table-valued-parameters

I made a function that takes a `varchar` (IP address) and returns table values (city, country, time_zone...)

```
ALTER function [dbo].[GQuery2](@ipAddress varchar(16)) 
 returns @t table (
    [country_name] [nvarchar](64) ,
    [region_name] [nvarchar](128) ,
    [city_name] [nvarchar](128),
    [latitude] [float],
    [longitude] [float] ,
    [zip_code] [nvarchar](30) ,
    [time_zone] [nvarchar](8) 
 )
 as 
 begin 
    insert into @t ([country_name]
      ,[region_name]
      ,[city_name]
      ,[latitude]
      ,[longitude]
      ,[zip_code]
      ,[time_zone])
 select  [country_name]
      ,[region_name]
      ,[city_name]
      ,[latitude]
      ,[longitude]
      ,[zip_code]
      ,[time_zone]
 from [pcap].[dbo].ip2loc 
 where ip_from = ( 
        select max(ip_from) 
            from [pcap].[dbo].ip2loc 
            where ip_from <= [dbo].IP2INT(@ipAddress) 
            ) 
 and ip_to = ( 
        select min(ip_to) 
            from [pcap].[dbo].ip2loc 
            where ip_to >= [dbo].IP2INT(@ipAddress) 
                ) 
    RETURN  
 end
```

The problem is I can only call the function in this format:

```
 SELECT * FROM [dbo].GQuery2('89.98.0.0')
```

and it returns a new table

```
country_name    region_name city_name   latitude    longitude   zip_code    time_zone
NETHERLANDS NOORD-HOLLAND   AMSTERDAM   52.37403    4.88969 1089    +02:00
```

And I want to make a query like this (theoretically)

```
UPDATE DimLocation d,  [dbo].GQuery2(d.ip) g 
SET d.city_name = g.city_name, d.country_name = g.country_name ....
```

The `DimLocation` table has the schema:

```
IP, country_name, region_name, city_name, latitude, longitude, zip_code, time_zone
```

The IP address has a value and the other columns are NULL and i need to pass the IP address from `DimLocation` to the function `GQuery2(ip)` to get the missing data

The question is how to work with table-valued functions in `select` statements?

Answer (score 0):

Try Following query:

```
Update DimLocation
Set City_Name = g.City_Name,
    Country_Name = g.Country_Name,
    ....
From dbo.GQuery2(DimLocation.IP) g
```

Comment: nothing
Update pcap.dbo.DimLocation
Set city_name = g.city_name From dbo.GQuery2(d.ip) g 

:(
The multi-part identifier "d.ip" could not be bound.

Answer (score 0):

Your function should contain `IP` field also to join the function with `DimLocation` table otherwise the query will update all the records in `DimLocation` table Or you have to update single record at a time (ie. `Where DimLocation.IP='192.168.0.1'`). But, It is better to do practice that retrieved records should have a field that you can match with the parent table which you want to update.

If you are adding the `IP` field in your function then the query should be written like this.

```
Update DimLocation Set DimLocation.City_Name = f.City_Name, DimLocation.Country_Name=f.Country_Name,.. 
From DimLocation Inner Join dbo.GQuery2(DimLocation.IP) f On DimLocation.IP=f.IP
```

Thus, you can update all values in the `DimLocation` table with your created function in a single query.